# migrate running on Virtual Box PostgreSql instance to another machine

Tags: virtualbox, postgresql

I have a PostgreSql instance that Run on Virtual Box at the Physical Machine A

This instance is collecting real-time data, so any downtime is undesirable.

I want to move this instance to the Physical Machine B (also under Virtual Box)

Are there any simple way to do it without stopping the running instance?

Answer (score 0):

This action is called `teleporting` in VirtualBox management. It is described in chapter 7.2 of the VirtualBox documentation ([teleporting](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#teleporting)). But it depends on your configuration meeting the requirements:

> At this time, there are a few prerequisites for this to work, however:
>
> 1. On the target host, you must configure a virtual machine in VirtualBox with exactly the same hardware settings as the machine on
>      the source that you want to teleport. This does not apply to settings
>      which are merely descriptive, such as the VM name, but obviously for
>      teleporting to work, the target machine must have the same amount of
>      memory and other hardware settings. Otherwise teleporting will fail
>      with an error message.
> 2. The two virtual machines on the source and the target **must share the same storage** (hard disks as well as floppy and CD/DVD images).
>      This means that they either use the same iSCSI targets or that the
>      storage resides somewhere on the network and both hosts have access to
>      it via NFS or SMB/CIFS.

Especially the second requirement (shared storage for the virtual disks) is usually not met.

Comment: Thanks.  If I am not mistaken  the source machine should start with the special flag "wait for teleport" so it would not work with the running instance.  Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: Where did you find this information? The documentation says `Start the machine on the source host as usual` - which means it may also be already running. Waiting for teleport is only essential on the target.